# Can Sharingan user have a pair of normal set of eyes transplant into them?

Tags: naruto

We all know Mangekyo Sharingan will blind its user over time right? And the only way is to transplant a set of new eyes from a close Uchiha into them and gains Eternal Mangekyo.

*So, I'm wondering if the new set of eyes isn't from Uchiha bloodline. I mean , a normal person without kekkei genkai? What would happen then? *

Comment: But why would an Uchiha do that?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose he should be able to see but no longer be able to use the Sharingan. It is not explicitly known what activates the Sharingan in an eye. But it is highly likely that it is hard coded in an Uchiha eye balls, since using those eyes, a person who is not from the Uchiha clan is able to use the Sharingan. Just like Kakashi and Danzo for instance.

From the same logic, an Uchiha should be able to see using normal eyes from another person but no longer be able to use the Sharingan. The ability is hard coded inside the eyes. The weakening of the sight in case of excessive use of Mangekyo Sharingan would also be nullified in case of normal eye transplants. Just like a normal eye transplant to a blind person.

Comment: Definition of sharingan: When an Uchiha experiences a powerful emotional condition with regards to a person precious to them, their brain releases a special form of chakra that affects the optic nerves, transforming the eyes into Sharingan

Comment: Like @JustDoIt said, we do know how the Uchiha get their Sharingan. My question to you, why did you say, "it is not explicitly known what activates the Sharingan in an eye", if it was said in both manga and anime?

Comment: I meant it as in we do not know about what causes sharingan to activate referring to the internal workings of an eye. I said it seems to be hard coded in an Uchiha eye. Think about this. If some special chakra of an Uchiha that activates the sharingan and an emotional state is all that is needed, then a blind Uchiha could simply get normal eyes transplanted and activate the sharingan in them, although he would probably able to start over. But it seems like they are only after the Uchiha eyes. It's understandable if they're after eternal sharingan. Like Madara. He was going blind. [Continued]

Comment: He could have used a normal pair of eyes. I mean it's better to be at least able to see than to have a pair of sharingan eyes that can't even see. But he only took the eyes of his brother. Although I am not aware if his brother gave them willingly or Madara forced him. Having normal eyes transplanted and awakening sharingan in them seems like a pretty simple and easy workaround for the blindness, yet we have never seen that sort of thing. Makes me think sharingan can nly be awakened in Uchiha eyes.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it was said in anime by reanimated Tobirama Senju that the Uchiha's brains released a special type of chakra upon experiencing a sad moment. So I feel that the eyes don't really matter here.

I think that if a skilled medical nin is able to transplant an Uchiha brain into a rabbit, have it reproduce and then kill the baby rabbit a few days later, the rabbit should awaken the Sharingan and then further a Mangekyou Sharingan. This could be a way to cultivate multiple Sharingan (Sharingan farm).

Then the rabbit's eye should be taken out and replaced with a normal eye (probably from the person who wants the Sharingan). Finally, transplant the eye into the normal person and he gets a free Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan.